# Wrong background color in custom QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, kde-plasma

In my GUI, I have a scrollable area and a widget to be displayed in it defined like so:

```cpp
_scoreBoxScroll = new QScrollArea(this);
_scoreBoxScroll->setFrameShape(QFrame::NoFrame);
_scoreBoxWidget = new QWidget(this);
_scoreBoxWidgetLayout = new QHBoxLayout(_scoreBoxWidget);
```

Some custom widgets are added later in a function:

```cpp
for (int i = 1; i <= _db->gamesPerRound(); ++i) {
    GameWidget *newGame = new GameWidget(_scoreBoxWidget, i, _db->playersString(MT::singular), _db->boogerScore());
    _scoreBoxWidgetLayout->addWidget(newGame);
}

_scoreBoxScroll->setWidget(_scoreBoxWidget);
```

This results in a wrong background color for the GameWidgets:
[image: Widgets with wrong background color]

When I add those widgets in the constructor with the very same code (and the _db calls replaced with static values, as when the constructor is called, there's no _db yet), the widgets are displayed with the correct color:
[image: Widgets with correct background color]

In case this is interesting: the whole code can be found in git://l3u.de/muckturnier.git, the posted code resides in ScorePage/ScorePage.cpp.

Why is a different color displayed here? And how can I fix this? Thanks in advance for all help!

Edit: the code in the constructor used in the second example is (as I don't have _db there):

```cpp
_scoreBoxWidget = new QWidget(this);
_scoreBoxWidgetLayout = new QHBoxLayout(_scoreBoxWidget);
_scoreBoxLayout->addWidget(_scoreBoxWidget);

for (int i = 1; i <= 2; ++i) {
    GameWidget *newGame = new GameWidget(this, i, QString::fromUtf8("Paar"), 21);
    _scoreBoxWidgetLayout->addWidget(newGame);
}

_scoreBoxScroll->setWidget(_scoreBoxWidget);
```

**Edit: I have created a minimalistic demo in the "demo" branch on git://l3u.de:muckturnier.git** – I would be very glad if anyone could explain this behaviour!

Comment: Would be helpful if you also provided the 'static' version of code where everything works fine. Don't mind me, but I'm a little suspicious when somebody says: "It's basically the same.".

Comment: I really just added the very code to the constructor, the only difference is: GameWidget *newGame = new GameWidget(this, i, QString::fromUtf8("Paar"), 21); and a literal 2 instead of _db->gamesPerRound().

Comment: Just tried it once again with the code added above. I simply commented out the content of the reload() function and added the code with the static values to the end of the constructor. Gives the results posted above, you can try it with the git code: just build it, create an empty database ("Neues Turnier starten"), and go to the "Spielergebnisse eintragen" Tab.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say: the code is currently in the "work" branch, not in master.

Comment: This is very interesting. The function containing the widget setup is ScorePage::reload(). It's called from another class holding a pointer to the ScorePage: MainWindow::setScoreTabEnabled(). If reload() is called from there, I get the wrong colors. When I call the same function (with _db calls changed to static values) from the constructor of ScorePage, the colors are correct. How can that make a difference?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I can answer my question myself now. It's due to the fact that QScrollArea::setWidget() calls setAutoFillBackground(true) on the added widget. When I add a manual

```
_scoreBoxWidget->setAutoFillBackground(false);
```

after the

```
_scoreBoxScroll->setWidget(_scoreBoxWidget);
```

the background color is as expected.